# Render ReactJs dynamic content in fixed layout

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJs and I don't know if I "thinking in the React way". This is my scenario:

I have a Header component and a Body content.
And I have a Layout component that render header and body. This is the fixed structure.

So I have a Dashboard component, but I need render the Dashboard inside the body component. And that's my problem, I don't know how to render the Dashboard component =/

Can someone help me?

Comment: You seem to compose Header and Body inside of the Layout component. What prevents you from composing the Body from Dashboard?
Or do you want Body to be some kind of container around changing Content?

Comment: Well, my first idea was to have a Body to be the app's container and change just the content.


After looking at my code for a while, I thought  each content component load the Body container but , even so, I still have to do some kind of "inject" to put de content in the middle of the container.


since I only want to change my content, I think the first option is better, but in both I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve nested, dynamic child components in React by using `this.props.children`.

If I understand correctly your app has the following structure:

```
<div>
  <Header />
  <Body />
</div>
```

You can nest components deeper than one level, so changing the above to

```
<div>
  <Header />
  <Body>
    <Dashboard />
  </Body>
</div>
```

allows you to render the **Dashboard** component (and/or whatever else is nested inside the `<Body>` tags) by writing `{this.props.children}` inside the **Body** component's render function.

You can use a conditional and render the wanted child component by using this technique.

You can read more about nested child components [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children).